# Custom UIViews are dissappearing after visiting a second detailViewController

Tags: ios, swift, uiview, uiviewcontroller

Ok, here's the thing. I created a **CommonViews** class, which holds an *UIImageView* and a *UILabel*, which both represents a **logo and the API credits respectively**. I did this because I wanted to apply the **DRY principle** to my code, so I figured out this refactoring. But it's behaviour is more than unexpected.

My app structure has 3 ViewControllers.

**MarvelViewController**, which has a CollectionVC with many characters, and each one of them pushes to a new controller.

```
class MarvelCollection: UIViewController {

. . .

var viewMarvel: UIView? = {
    
    let view = UIView()
    view.backgroundColor = Colors.mainBlack
    return view
}()

var collViewHeroes: UICollectionView? = {

    let layout = UICollectionViewFlowLayout()
    let cv = UICollectionView(frame: .zero,
                              collectionViewLayout: layout)
    . . .
    return cv
}()
. . .
}
```

**DetailViewController** is the next one, which shows detailed information about any selected character. It also has a comics section (another CollectionVC), which leads us to the next one.

```
class DetailViewController: UIViewController {

. . .


var comicCollectionView: UICollectionView? = {
    let layout = UICollectionViewFlowLayout()
    let cv = UICollectionView(frame: .zero,
                              collectionViewLayout: layout)
    . . .
    return cv
}()

. . .
}
```

**ComicDetailViewController**, where I show all the detailed information about the comics where every character appears on.

```
class ComicDetailViewController: UIViewController {

. . .

var viewMarvel: UIView? = {
    
    let view = UIView()
    view.backgroundColor = Colors.mainBlack
    return view
}()

. . .
}
```

Both *MarvelVC* and *ComicDetailVC* calls the `commonViews.setCommonViews(parentView: viewMarvel)` func, because I wanna show the logo and the credits for each screen. My *DetailVC* works as a bridge between this two.

```
   func setCommonViews(parentView: UIView) {
    
    //MARK: - Common Logo
    guard let imgViewLogo = imgViewLogo else { return }
    parentView.addSubview(imgViewLogo)
    
    imgViewLogo.anchor(top: parentView.safeAreaLayoutGuide.topAnchor, paddingTop: 28, bottom: nil,
                       paddingBottom: 0, left: parentView.leftAnchor, paddingLeft: 0,
                       right: parentView.rightAnchor, paddingRight: 0,
                       width: 0, height: view.frame.height/6)
    
    //MARK: - Common Credits
    guard let creditsLabel = creditsLabel else { return }
    parentView.addSubview(creditsLabel)
        
    creditsLabel.anchor(top: nil, paddingTop: 0, bottom: parentView.safeAreaLayoutGuide.bottomAnchor, paddingBottom: 0, left: parentView.leftAnchor, paddingLeft: 0, right: parentView.rightAnchor, paddingRight: 0, width: 0, height: 20)
}
```

So, the "weird behavior" I'm talking about, is that, when I run my app, both logo and credits appears on my *MarvelVC*. This is ok. Then, I can click on any cell, go to my *DetailVC* and then see the comics collectionView. Fine too. Then, if I click any comic, I can see my *ComicDetailVC*, and as any of us would expect, there are the logo and the credits.

If I press "back" twice on my navBar, and go to my *MarvelVC* again *(my first ViewController)*, I'll find something funny. **The logo and credits are gone.** If I try to select another characterCell and go back, I won't see any change. I've already *erased all content and settings* of the simulator, I tried *bringing to the front the logo and the credits*, but none of it worked.

I think I explained myself ok, but if u need something like a gif showing up the weird behavior, let me know. I hope u guys can help me on this random bug.

**EDIT1:** Function where I call **setCommonViews**. I call `setMarvelCollectionViews` in the *MarvelVC* `viewDidLoad` method.

```
    func setMarvelCollectionViews() {
        
        . . .
        
        /// Create the mainView and add it to the controller safely
        guard let viewMarvel = viewMarvel else { return }
        view.addSubview(viewMarvel)
        
        commonViews.setCommonViews(parentView: viewMarvel)
        
        . . .

        viewMarvel.anchor(top: view.topAnchor, paddingTop: 0, bottom: view.bottomAnchor, paddingBottom: 0, left: view.leftAnchor, paddingLeft: 0, right: view.rightAnchor, paddingRight: 0, width: 0, height: 0)
    }
```

Comment: Do you set `translatesAutoResizingMaskIntoConstraints` to `false` for your views?  How do you create the instances of `CommonViews` that each VC uses?

Comment: Also there is no reason to declare your view properties as optionals.

Comment: Rather than having a function `setCommonViews` you should have `CommonView` which subclasses `UIView`. This view would add the image View and label sub views to itself and set any constraints between those sub views. Your view controllers would add an instance of `CommonView` to its own view hierarchy and set constraints on it. This way you decouple the common view from its parent.

Comment: @Paulw11 I created a global variable to instantiate CommonViews. I also did what u said about `translatesAutoResizingMaskIntoConstraints `, and the bug remains.

Comment: I also erased the optionals and same result.

Comment: The optionals aren't your issue, they are just unnecessary and lead you to have to unwrap when there is no need. You haven't shown how/where you call `setCommonViews`

Comment: A global isn't going to work. If you use a global then you only have one instance and you can't have the same sub views added to multiple view hierarchies at the same time. I strongly suggest that you refactor so that your `CommonView` into a `UIView` subclass so that you can add an instance to each VC

Comment: I've added the setCommonViews call.

Comment: At the very least you need to change it to `CommonViews().setCommonViews(parentView:viewMarvel)` so that you are using a separate instance. `viewMarvel` is pointless as well. You can just use `self.view` and change the background color of `self.view` to black.

Comment: Yep, my problem was that I had the CommonViews instance globally. It worked now that I instantiated it on each controller.